# Exporting a form to be used by another user

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a friend who has signed up for Cognito Forms and he wants to use a form that I designed.

How can I export the form so that he can import it into his account?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can share a form that you have set up by turn on the 'Share as Template?' feature on the Build page of your form. Once turned on you will need to save your form. Then you can just send them the provided template link.

[image]

They will be able to open a preview of them form, then save a copy of the form to their Organization.

You can learn more about this process in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/17/building-forms/form-settings#sharing-a-form-as-a-template).